# Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ljuni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Yesterday I was programming with Ionic when then I came across this error, and the previous solutions that were tested were not able to fix it. Could you help me solve this problem?

[[image: Image of error]

Comment: did you install ionic? `npm i ionic -g`?

Comment: Yes. This problem started after I updated the ionic I had for the latest version released.

Comment: try `npm cache clean` and try again..

Comment: also what is your npm version?

Comment: npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
I tried this and then reinstalled the ionic and cord, but those errors appeared.:                                                                                             
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ljuni\Desktop\Angular & Ionic\iweather\node_modules\.staging\ionic-dec5da97
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

Comment: try updating your node and npm and try to install ionic

Comment: Version 3.10.10

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help.